# Why and when we need File Channels in java?

Tags: java, filechannel

This is the very time I came across working with File Channels. Where I'm putting a lock on channel to lock the process to avoid other process to use it.

While reading online, I got to know that Channel is like an endpoint to access file with I/O operation but it always read and write from buffer.

Here is an example I came across

```
 String filePath = "readfile.txt";
 printFileContents(filePath);
 Path path = Paths.get(filePath);

 FileChannel fileChannel =  FileChannel.open(path);
 ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(6); 
 int noOfBytesRead = fileChannel.read(buffer);
```

In 5th line, buffer is being created of limit 6. But I'm confused in last step. Buffer is just empty but a limit of 6, filechannel should read from buffer but ow its happening here ?Does filechannel puts first limit of 6 content in buffer than read it from there ?

Could any one help me to understand this, how it works ? And what's the actual purpose of using Filechannels ?